# JavaScript functions inside of JavaScript functions, closures, et al

Tags: javascript

When I declare `OnSuccess` inside another function like below, the browser developer tools console indicates an error that there's no function called `OnSuccess` in the global scope. From this, I infer that any functions declared like below inside another function are still hoisted/pinned/treated as functions of the HTML DOM `window` object.

Then, I declare `OnError` like you declare a member inside an object initializer. That doesn't work either.

One way I could do is move both `OnError` and `OnSuccess` outside the `AssignBackupOnServer` function, but I want the `OnSuccess` and `OnError` to be able to look at the local variables of the `AssignBackupOnServer`, so I have declared it within the `AssignBackupOnServer` function.

What's the right way of going about this declaration if I want the contained lambda to exhibit a closure on the captured variables of its containing/enclosing function?

```
function AssignBackupOnServer(mainGuyUId, backupUId, backupFirstName, backupLastName) {

    var url = '/Foo/SearchForBackup';

    $.ajax(url,
        {
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(
            { 
              'mainGuyUId': mainGuyUId, 
              'backupUId': backupUId, 
              'backupFirstName': backupFirstName, 
              'backupLastName': backupLastName 
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: AssignBackupOnServer.OnSuccess,
            error: AssignBackupOnServer.OnError
        });

    function OnSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // I want to use mainGuyUId, backupUId, 
        // backupFirstName, and backupLastName
        // here and therefore, I want this function
        // to exhibit a closure on its containing lambda
        // so I have declared it here
    }

    OnError : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with the OnSuccess but just slightly wrong when referencing it. You don't need the `AssignBackupOnServer.` prefix:

```
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});

function OnSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
}

function OnError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you. :-) That's the thing I'd done at first, but I can't remember if it gave me an error or not with that. Please let me try that and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to declare an identifier in the function `AssignBackupOnServer` for both functions and use those identifiers directly intstead of `AssignBackupOnServer`.  For example

```
function onSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
  ...
}

function onError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
  ...
}

$.ajax(url,
        {
         ...
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I see you are willing to reuse the `onSuccess` and `onError` functions but access the outer variables. If that's not the case Richard's answer is what you need.
If it is I would suggest a more functional approach:

```
function makeSuccess(mainGuyUId, backupUId, backupFirstName, backupLastName){
  return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // Here you have access to everything
    // and you can use the function elsewhere
  }
}

function makeError(mainGuyUId, backupUId, backupFirstName, backupLastName){
  return function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // Here you have access to everything
    // and you can use the function elsewhere
  }
}

function AssignBackupOnServer(mainGuyUId, backupUId, backupFirstName, backupLastName) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  var url = '/Foo/SearchForBackup';

  $.ajax(url,
    {
      //...
      success: makeSuccess.apply(this,args),
      error: makeError.apply(this,args)
    });
}
```

Comment: Why did you need to call `slice` on the `arguments`? Why not just assign `var args = arguments;`?